# How to catch all coroutine uncaught exception in android without changing ```scope.launch {...}```?

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, coroutine

I'm wondering if there is a Coroutine way to catch all Uncaught exception from any scope in android ?

I try with the `Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler` and it works but i'm wondering if this can be enable in an other way.

EDIT : I want to have the global exception handling without changing the coroutine launch. (leave the `scope.launch {...}` as is)

Comment: There is no exception handler that will just catch all exceptions without changing the launch as you say. The only thing you have at that point is to use `Thread.uncaughtExceptionHandler` which will catch ALL exceptions in your app

Answer (score 3):

You can using CEH (Coroutine Exception Handler) similar `Thread.uncaughtExceptionHandler` like this:

```
class ExceptionHandlerViewModel(
    private val apiHelper: ApiHelper,
    private val dbHelper: DatabaseHelper
) : ViewModel() {

    private val users = MutableLiveData<Resource<List<ApiUser>>>()

    private val exceptionHandler = CoroutineExceptionHandler { _, exception ->
        users.postValue(Resource.error("Something Went Wrong", null))
    }

    fun fetchUsers() {
        viewModelScope.launch(exceptionHandler) {
            users.postValue(Resource.loading(null))
            val usersFromApi = apiHelper.getUsers()
            users.postValue(Resource.success(usersFromApi))
        }
    }

    fun getUsers(): LiveData<Resource<List<ApiUser>>> {
        return users
    }

}
```

For more information : https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coroutines/exception-handling.html#coroutineexceptionhandler

Comment: I have already fine this but i do not want to change all my launch code line. I want to have the global exception handling without changing the corutine launch.

Comment: Right now, coroutines not support for global exception handling for all scope. But you can provide global `coroutineScope` and every `launch` run in this scope so you handle exception in root scope.